# Is correct to open multiple ports in Ubuntu and Nginx?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ports

About this issue: [Nginx Gunicorn one ip multiple django sites in folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47491737/nginx-gunicorn-one-ip-multiple-django-sites-in-folders)

I've already solve my problem opening multiple ports in my Ubuntu server based in this post https://serverfault.com/questions/655067/is-it-possible-to-make-nginx-listen-to-different-ports, but I still have a few questions about that:

1. Is it correct to open multiple ports to serve multiple instances for the same app?
2. If that is correct, how can I hide the port in the url for the users? To access one instance, they (the user) must type "http://1.1.1.1:81/app1/" or "http://1.1.1.1:82/app2/". Is this a good idea?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't use a custom port and not have it in the URL.  http://site.example/ is a shorthand for http://site.example:80/ and similarly the port implied by https is 443 and if it's a different port you have to have it explicitly in the URL.

Comment: @tripleee thanks for ur clear answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Yes**, you could do that. I would also say you should utilize multiple subdomains as seen in the above answer.
2. **That is not bad**, as you only define a specific port. I have also done it and it works just as normal.

Comment: Thanks @Viper. Have a link about your second answer to see your config?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of routing based on ports, I would route based on either domain name or subdomain name.  So, instead of www.mysite.com:8000, www.mysite.com:8001, and so on, you would have something like subdomain1.mysite.com, subdomain2.mysite.com, etc.

Here's another discussion that covers this:  [route different proxy based on subdomain request in nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21064401/route-different-proxy-based-on-subdomain-request-in-nginx)